# Iterating through a json in python - only wanting the value for one key in multiple dicts

Tags: python, json

I have this Json file, and I want to get the "navn" out with a iterating.
I need it to print:
Traktor
Bil and nothing else, how do I do that ?

```
[
    {"navn": "Traktor", "år": 10, "købspris": 10000},
    {"navn": "Bil", "år": 20, "købspris": 100000},
    {},
    {}
    ]
```

So far I have this idea
I know I need to import json file, and iterating through it but every time it gives me a error... I have tried searching the whole wide web and nothing came up
my code so far:

```
import json
def main():
    f = open("/Users/maltheschroderjakobsen/Desktop/coding/test/mat.json",)
    f = json.load(f)
    for key in f["navn"]:
        print (key)    
main()
```

But every time I try anything else it gives me a error

Comment: Please show the code. Saying that you get an error without any details is just way too vague

Comment: It Is now up :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because some dicts have no key `navn`. Use `dict.get` instead:

```py
import json
def main():
    file = open("/Users/maltheschroderjakobsen/Desktop/coding/test/mat.json",)
    data = json.load(file)
    for dct in data:
        print(dct.get("navn", ""))
main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

So long as the JSON **only** has dicts, you can do:

```
js='''\
[
    {"navn": "Traktor", "år": 10, "købspris": 10000},
    {"navn": "Bil", "år": 20, "købspris": 100000},
    {},
    {}
]'''
    
import json 

>>> [e['navn'] for e in json.loads(js) if e.get('navn', '')]
['Traktor', 'Bil']
```

JSON can also have other datatypes such as lists or numeral. If there is a possibility of something other than a `dict` in the JSON, you can do:

```
[e['navn'] for e in json.loads(js) if isinstance(e, dict) and e.get('navn', '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` seems to be a list, not a dictionary:

```
for dct in f:
    if "navn" in dct:  # the elements are dicts!
        print(dct["navn"])
```